# variable is not defined in cypress

Tags: cypress, alias

I am using this code to make random selection. But in the end of this code I want to save the variable to use further in the test-cases. I did so, but I got the error

```
cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item') // we get the select/option by finding the select by class
    .then(listing => {        
      const randomNumber = getRandomInt(0, listing.length-1); //generate a rendom number between 0 and length-1. In this case 0,1,2
      cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item').eq(randomNumber).then(($select) => {              //choose an option randomly
        const text = $select.text()       //get the option's text. For ex. "A"
        cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper').contains(text).click()       // select the option on UI
        let region = text;
        cy.wrap(region).as('region')
      });    
    })
    cy.log(region)
```

Comment: Can you not call `cy.log` immediately after `cy.wrap` - which will be called in the future of `cy.get` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in case you want to use the value of the region within the same test (same `it` block).

```js
cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item') // we get the select/option by finding the select by class
  .then((listing) => {
    const randomNumber = getRandomInt(0, listing.length - 1) //generate a rendom number between 0 and length-1. In this case 0,1,2
    cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item')
      .eq(randomNumber)
      .then(($select) => {
        //choose an option randomly
        const text = $select.text() //get the option's text. For ex. "A"
        cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper').contains(text).click() // select the option on UI
        let region = text
        cy.wrap(region).as('region')
      })
  })

cy.get('@region').then((region) => {
  cy.get('selector').type(region)
})
```

In case if you use the value of text, in different test(different `it` block) or even different test suite you can do this:

```js
cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item') // we get the select/option by finding the select by class
  .then((listing) => {
    const randomNumber = getRandomInt(0, listing.length - 1) //generate a rendom number between 0 and length-1. In this case 0,1,2
    cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item')
      .eq(randomNumber)
      .then(($select) => {
        //choose an option randomly
        const text = $select.text() //get the option's text. For ex. "A"
        cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper').contains(text).click() // select the option on UI
        let region = text
        Cypress.env('region', region)
      })
  })

cy.get('selector').type(Cypress.env('region'))
```

Comment: How can I use this in future? Can I do something like this - cy.get('div.text').type(region)? I want to use this variable in my tests

Comment: e.g. I need to check if element contains region

Comment: `region` alias has already the region name. what do you want to do it

Comment: When I use this code cy.get('selector').should('have.text',region). region isn't defined

Comment: Are you using the `Cypres.env()` method?

Comment: I do so - cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item').should('have.text',Cypress.env(region))

Comment: you are missing quotes `cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item').should('have.text',Cypress.env('region'))`

Comment: but when i use -  cy.xpath('selector').should('have.text', Cypress.env('region')) - I get Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<selector>' to have text undefined, but the text was 'Oregon'

Comment: Can you do a log like `cy.log(Cypress.env('region'))` and check what are you getting.

Comment: I got an empty log

Comment: Ok then this line `const text = $select.text() ` is causing the problem. Can you check that this line `cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item').eq(randomNumber)` is actually gives the inner text you are looking for. Add a `cy.log(text)` and check.

Comment: it works as it selects random option

Comment: What does this print `cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item').eq(randomNumber).invoke('text').then((text) => {
  cy.log(text)
})`

Comment: may be it is so because I used the first approach. I'll try the second one

Comment: I got the following `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '' to have text ' N. Virginia ', but the text was 'N. Virginia'`. My variable `region` contains space at the beginning, how to remove it

Comment: Add `trim()` to remove spaces. `$select.text().trim()`.

Answer (score 7):

Add `.then()` to your log, and move the declaration of `region` to the top.

```js
let region;

cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item')
    .then(listing => {        
      const randomNumber = getRandomInt(0, listing.length-1); //generate a rendom number between 0 and length-1. In this case 0,1,2
      cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper nz-option-item').eq(randomNumber).then(($select) => {              //choose an option randomly
        const text = $select.text()       //get the option's text. For ex. "A"
        cy.get('div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper').contains(text).click()       // select the option on UI
        region = text;
        cy.wrap(region).as('region')
      });    
    })

cy.then(() => {
   cy.log(region)
})
```

Comment: How can I use this in future? Can I do something like this - cy.get('div.text').type(region)? I want to use this variable in my tests